# Test WF 4.0 Delay activity -- Replace DurableTimerExtension with my own MockTimerExtension

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I want to provide my own implementation of TimerExtention in place of DurableTimerExtention provided by Delay activity, so that I can test workflows that use delays.

How can I accomplish that?

I have WorkflowService instance and its root Activity. The workflow service is hosted in WorkflowServiceHost, (though I can not figure out how to get WorkflowInstance instance)

Answer (score 1):

One way to test your workflows is to use the Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting on [CodePlex](http://wf.codeplex.com/). It has the capability to mock activities using XAML Injection. See [here](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20do%20I%20mock%20activities%20when%20testing%20Workflow%20Services%20with%20XAML%20Injection?&referringTitle=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview) for more details.

In the case of a Delay activity you can do things a lot simpler though. Instead of hard coding the Duration to a fixed value I normally create a config object with the duration in there. In the Delay activity I just enter an expression like `Settings.WaitForPaymentDuration`. In production the `Settings.WaitForPaymentDuration` will be set to something like 30 days but in a test I can set it to 1 second instead without changing the workflow at all.

Comment: I want to be able not to just replace 30 days with 1 second, but to control the time. I.e. I want the delay activities to work off of a given 'ISystemClock { DateTime Now { get; } }' instance. The problem with using XamlInjector is that I have to reimplement whole Delay activity with the only difference of a TimerExtension it supplies (that's what I ended up doing). Ideally I want to _just_ substitute DurableTimerExtension with a mock one, without having to mess with Delay activity.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar interest in [mocking the `TimerExtension`](http://itdoesntmatterwhatyoudo.blogspot.com/2012/11/unit-testing-long-running-workflows-by.html), I wrote a blog post about it.  In that post I inject my own implementation of the `TimerExtension` using `WorkflowApplication.Extensions.Add<T>(Func<T>)`.  `WorkflowServiceHost` also has this collection. You could replace the concrete class I have in my example with a mock.  I wrote it targeting 4.5, but it should work with anything that uses the Extension collection.  Its in 4, not sure earlier versions.

[[Link]](http://itdoesntmatterwhatyoudo.blogspot.com/2012/11/unit-testing-long-running-workflows-by.html)